# how can i get the count of key , value pair in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

firebase key-value pair count all I need but I don't know how we can get the count of key-value pair in firebase please let me know if have the solution for this thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can count children this way.

```
databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e(snap.getKey(),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR REPLY IT SAVES MY TIME.